# Fetch data and set the state. Then make the data available to the app using the context api

Tags: reactjs

Fetch data and set the state. Then make the data available to the app using the context api.

Fetch the data and return a promise

```
const getData = async function () {
  try {
    const data = await axios.get(
      "https://VALID_URL.json"
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

```
export const StoreProvider = (props) => {
  const [allProducts, setAllProducts] = useState({});

  // Was setting the state here but didn't work. It's coming back as undefined
  useEffect(() => {
    getData().then((data) => console.log(data));
    console.log("USEEFFECT");
  }, []);

  return (
    <StoreContext.Provider value={allProducts}>
      {props.children}
    </StoreContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: *Did* you try setting the state? `setAllProducts` is unused. Please give a [mre].

Comment: Was using setAllProducts but it wasn't causing a re-render so changed in to see what it was returning and it was undefined.

Comment: You don't return anything from `getData`...

Comment: Wow... Yeah that was it... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot to return the promise returned data from your `getData` method.

Try returning the resolved promise:

```js
const getData = async function () {
  return await axios.get(https://VALID_URL.json);
};
```

In your component, you arent setting the data to state

```js
export const StoreProvider = (props) => {
  const [allProducts, setAllProducts] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    getData().then((data) => setAllProducts(data));
  }, []);
```

Everything else looks good.

**EDIT:**

If you are trying to load data from a JSON file which resides in your project, then your just need to require the file like:

```js
const data = require("./path-to-file/myfile.json")
```

Comment: Returning it solved my issue. Thanks!